# Div moves on top of div on some screen sizes

Tags: html, css

On a specific range of screen sizes (in the low 1000s), I have a content div that will move over a navigation div completely. It's as if both divs begin at the top of the page.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body id="about">
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="selected">About</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="left">
            <h4><b>Lots of text.../b><h4>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6" id="right">
            <img class="rounded" src="IMG-5-12-2017.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 993px) {
    body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;    
    }
    #myTopnav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }   
    .row {
        margin: 0;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }
    #left h4 {
        margin: 5em;
    }
}
.rounded {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 65%;
}
#left {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#left h4 {
    line-height: 150%;
}
#right {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Why would the `row` div move on top of the `myTopnav` div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given your `#myTopnav` an absolute position. This takes it out of the flow of page.

It means you must handle spacing other elements so they do not to overlap the absolutely positioned ones.

In your case, you need to give your `row` class a margin that matches the height of `#myTopnav` element.

Since `row` is a class that is probably used in many places, you should probably add a new css class and use that to set the spacing. e.g.

```
<div class="row with-spacing">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="left">
            <h4><b>Lots of text.../b><h4>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6" id="right">
            <img class="rounded" src="IMG-5-12-2017.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 993px) {
    .row.with-spacing {
            margin-top:50px;
        }
}
```